# How to compute the centroid of a polygon in Python

Tags: python, openstreetmap, postgis

I am wondering if there any algorithm where I can compute the center of a polygon in OSM because I've found that each polygon has a different parameters expression:

```
"POLYGON((-171379.35 5388068.23,-171378.8 5388077.59,-171368.44 5388076.82,-171368.89 5388067.46,-171379.35 5388068.23))"

"POLYGON((-171379.3 5374226.42,-171375.96 5374227.32,-171378.95 5374239.82,-171365.69 5374243.03,-171364.16 5374237.14,-171365.92 5374236.76,-171364.26 5374230.26,-171362.67 5374230.63,-171360.11 5374220.19,-171376.6 5374216.13,-171379.3 5374226.42))"
```

In this expression each one has a different number of parameters so how can i compute the centroid of it?

I am using the postgis to get the polygon information from the spatial information.

Comment: I found this code using numpy: http://oles-tutorials.googlecode.com/svn-history/r42/trunk/scipy2011/geoprocessing_tutorial/exercises/exercise4.py

Comment: ST_Centroid, as posted by MaM, will give you the answer, but if you want to understand the formula/theory, look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid towards the bottom.

Answer (score 11):

The polygons are described using [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry).

Using Python? Use [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/).

```
from shapely import wkt
p1 = wkt.loads("POLYGON((-171379.35 5388068.23,-171378.8 5388077.59,
                -171368.44 5388076.82,-171368.89 5388067.46,
                -171379.35 5388068.23))")
p2 = wkt.loads("POLYGON((-171379.3 5374226.42,-171375.96 5374227.32,
                -171378.95 5374239.82,-171365.69 5374243.03,
                -171364.16 5374237.14,-171365.92 5374236.76,
                -171364.26 5374230.26,-171362.67 5374230.63,
                -171360.11 5374220.19,-171376.6 5374216.13,
                -171379.3 5374226.42))")
print(p1.centroid.wkt) # POINT (-171373.8710815240337979 5388072.5175872016698122)
print(p2.centroid.wkt) # POINT (-171370.4190352254081517 5374229.0108996396884322)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PostGIS functionality](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Centroid.html) or for example the python lib [shapely](https://web.archive.org/web/20121015010336/http://forrst.com/posts/Find_the_centroid_of_any_SimpleGeo_polygon_using-zrK) to realize it.